# What is better? Querying file system or querying database?

Tags: sql-server, performance, asp.net-mvc-3, filesystems

We have about half a million images residing in the file system. Multiple images belong to a product and named after ProductID. For example, Product ID 10010 has 3 images; 10010_1.jpg, 10010_2.jpg and 10010_3.jpg. To display these 3 images in photo gallery, current code in classic ASP is querying the file system. The code looks something like this:

```
Dim objFSO, i
Set objFSO = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
i=1
While objFSO.FileExists(Server.MapPath(productid & "_" & i & ".jpg")
    ' draw the image
    i = i + 1
WEnd
```

Isn't it better idea to keep the image names in a database table and run a query to get the list of images available for a given product? I am pretty sure that reading it from the database is better. Just reluctant because I need a big table with half million records. Which way is more efficient?

My table will look something like this:

```
ID      ProductID   ImageURL
-------------------------------------------
1       10010       10010_1.jpg
2       10010       10010_2.jpg
3       10010       10010_3.jpg
4       10011       10011_1.jpg
. . .
```

Any suggestions? I am re-writing the web site in ASP .NET MVC 3. Anything extra I need to take care of in this platform/Framework?

Comment: Are all these files in the same directory?

Comment: In 4 directories. Depending upon image size.

Comment: use database is much better,if your db have 1million record the performance not going down but when use file system solution your app going to dead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Half a million records in a database is not really that big.

If your table is indexed correctly then you will get far better performance from a database than the file system.

Answer (score 3):

IMO, you can implement one of two solutions.

1. Hybrid - Use the database to store the filepath to the file as it exists on the filesystem.
2. NoSQL - Move completely away from the database and go with a NoSQL solution which provides an API to access files on the filesystem.

I have seen both implementations used, #1 before the advent of #2 became popular. Even though I have been using #1 longer, I feel that #2 is the best alternative for storing "asset" data (images, html descriptions, video files). The primary reason that NoSQL is better than MySQL with respect to accessing asset data, is you are not wasting precious database connections just to pull filepaths.

Also, another recommendation; chunk out your directories using the productids as the parent directories. Consider this:

```
# yours
dir1
  ... 125K files
dir2
  ... 125K files

# chunked (parent dirs are product ids)
3
  ... 3 files
4 
  ... 2 files
5 
  ... 3 files
```

It is much faster to stat files in a directory where there are only a few (< 100 files) than it is to stat files in a directory where there are several thousand files.

Comment: NoSQL sounds like a good idea. I need to do some research on that.

Comment: Here is a great SO post asking about NoSQL solutions for .net: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777103/what-nosql-solutions-are-out-there-for-net

Answer (score 0):

Yes, storing file path in DB makes total sence and would be better even if there some performance loss.

Note that having data on disk (file) and database (path to a file) makes new class of errors possible for the application where data is inconsistent. Take it into account during migration.

Since there is performance part of the question - prototype and measure for **your** data set if performance is concern. Things to take into account when prototyping/measuring:

- you don't need to build site for that, simple console application that reads data from disk/database would likly be enough to start.
- try different file layouts too (i.e. storing huge number of files in one directory may slow down searching for files)
- make sure you know if data will be cached. If your database too large so it can't be cached you'll get completely different numbers vs case when it fits in memory. Don't forget that depending on server configuration some other services may compete dfor the same memory too.

Comment: Images are in file system, I don't want to move them to db. Only file name and path that I want to store in db.

Comment: Time to sleep... after re-reading your question all my answer make not much sense... Yes, storing file path in DB makes total sence and would be better even if there some performance loss (which is highly unlikely).

Comment: Updated answer since it made no sense in relation to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something to think about. I'm assuming it's a .NET stack, so:

1. Database space is expensive
2. Reading from disk will be faster than reading from relational database
3. You will have more problems in load balanced environment if all your images are in the database
4. Reading large amount of data from the database will have a negative impact on other queries
5. It doesn't matter whether your presentation layer is MVC, web forms or console application. Your problem is in database design.

Comment: I want to store image name and path in the database not the whole image. And instead of querying the file system whether the image exists, I want to run a query the database.